# Spring AOP expression

Tags: spring, aop

I'm getting this error on the webapp startup

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Here's part of the xml showing my pointcut at the bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

..... things omitted

```
  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="bamAspectAroundID" ref="bamAspectAround">
        <aop:pointcut id="bamAroundMethodPointcut" expression="execution(* testBA*(..))" />
        <aop:around method="aspectAroundMethod" pointcut-ref="bamAroundMethodPointcut"/>
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>
```

in one of my classes, I have a dummy method

```
    public void testBAM() {
       System.out.println("in testBAM() ");
    }
```

The expression seems okay to me.  any pointers?  we're using aspectj 1.6.2.   thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your AspectJ expression is fine. I did a test version using what you gave us above and it worked.

I did not do it in a web container - I did it in Eclipse as a standalone Spring app using AspectJ tools 1.6.6 and AspectJ weaver 1.6.8 and Spring 3.1 libraries, so slightly ahead of your set up in terms of versions.

Here's what I have that worked:

The aspect related jar files in my classpath are:

- org.springframework.aop-3.1.0
- org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0
- com.springsource.org.aspectj.tools-1.6.6
- com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver-1.6.8
- com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0

The AOP part of my xml config looks exactly like yours - no changes.

I added the following bean definitions to the same spring xml config file:

```
<bean id="aspectTarget"    class="foo.bam.Target" />
<bean id="bamAspectAround" class="foo.bam.BamAspectAround" />
```

The Target class has your `testBAM()` method.

The code for the BamAspectAround looks like this:

```
public class BamAspectAround {
  public void aspectAroundMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(">>> BamAspectAround Before");
    joinPoint.proceed();
    System.out.println("<<< BamAspectAround After");
  }
}
```

The main method has this:

```
Target t = (Target)ctx.getBean("aspectTarget");
t.testBAM();
```

And it prints outs what I expected:

```
>>> BamAspectAround Before
in testBAM() 
<<< BamAspectAround After
```

**Note**: I also downloaded AspectJ 1.6.2 and put its weaver jar and its tools jar into my classpath (removing the 1.6.8 ones) and the above also worked, so perhaps try this simple example with your setup and see what piece you are missing from your web-deployed version.